# Conexão FTP em Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, iis, ftp, filezilla

Eu tenho um servidor **Win Server 2012 R2** que está com o IIS instalado e com um site FTP criado, também criei um usuário para utilização do FTP.

Configurei como porta externa para conexão FTP no firewall a porta: 2121, pois não posso estar utilizando a porta 21.

Da minha máquina fiz alguns testes utilizando telnet:

```
telnet meuIpExterno 2121
```

Resposta:

> 220 Microsoft FTP Service

Mas ao tentar conectar pelo FileZilla ou mesmo com o mando ftp no cmd não consigo executar nenhum comando.

Pelo FileZilla tenho este retorno:

> Estado:    Conectando 177.36.237.32:2121...
>  Estado:    Conexão
>   estabelecida, esperando mensagem de boas-vindas...
>   Estado:    Identificado
>  Estado:    Obtendo lista de pastas...
>   Comando:    PWD
>  Resposta:    257 "/" is current directory.
>   Comando:    TYPE I
>  Resposta:    200 Type set to I.
>  Comando:    PASV
>   Resposta:    227 Entering Passive Mode (177,36,237,32,192,41).
>   Comando:    LIST
>  Resposta:    150 Opening BINARY mode data
>   connection.
>  Erro:    A conexão de dados não pode ser estabalecida:
>   ECONNREFUSED - Conexão recusada pelo servidor
>  Erro:    Conexão
>   expirou após 20 segundos de inatividade
>  Erro:    Falha na obtenção da
>   lista de pastas

Já testei várias coisas sem sucesso. Estou conseguindo me conectar mas não tenho acesso.

Comment: Criou esse usuário como? Por algum painel? Usa que software no servidor para FTP? Creio que seu usuário não tenha permissões para executar comandos e então o servidor o rejeite, não posso afirmar nada sem mais detalhes. (restaurei a tag iis, acho que entendi melhor o problema)

Comment: O servidor é meu, todos as configurações que fiz foi utilizando o user administrator. Configurei o firewall e criei o usuário pelo manager do proprio windows. Criei o servidor FTP com o IIS.

Comment: Mas no IIS manager, você deu as permissões?

Comment: Sim está tudo configurado, por isso não sei o que fazer.

Comment: O problema está em obter a lista de pastas, pois a conexão está funcionando, ja fiz diversos testes.

Comment: Eu não estou falando da conexão, estou falando de **permissões de "comandos"**, Você verificou se adicionou as "permissões"? Sabe usar o IIS manager? Você criou o usuário por ele, certo? Do lado do autenticação ftp tem outro icone, acho que esta escrito como autorização FTP, nele creio que você libera as permissões, mas não tenho o IIS manager no momento para confirmar isto.

Comment: Sim, eu adicionei o usuario no iis

Comment: Tá, mas eu não fiz só uma pergunta, você entendeu o que eu disse afinal? Você entendeu sobre permissões? No IIS manager tem mais de um "icone" do FTP, por favor confere isto, se não conseguir vou tentar criar uma resposta de como fazer o passo a passo.

Comment: Pode ser uma configuração pendente no Filezilla. Que tal checar este procedimento e nos dizer se funcionou? https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/como-corrigir-econnrefused-conexao-recusada-por-erro-do-servidor-no-filezilla/

Comment: O problema não é com autenticação ou autorização, eu estou conseguindo acessar o server ftp com o usuario, consigo até criar e excluir pasta, por alguma razão não consigo listar. E não é um problema com o filezilla, pois obtive o mesmo problema por outros meios.